# Stuck with Apostolico-Crochemore algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm, full-text-search

I am trying to understand the Apostolico-Crochemore algorithm.

The only English description I have found is http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node12.html#SECTION00120, but I am stuck with the second line of the description where it says

> x is a power of a single character

What does that mean?

`m` in this case is the length of the pattern, `c` is a character from the alphabet in use. I can't understand how `x == c^m`.

This is then followed by `(x=(a^l)bu` for `a`, `b` in `Sigma`, `u` in `Sigma` and `a neq b` that also uses `^` operation which I cannot understand.

Comment: Awesome, being downvoted without explanation :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algorithms on strings are sometimes described in the jargon of formal languages, where concatenation (joining) of strings is written as multiplication: `x * y`, usually written just `xy`, means "the string `x` followed by the string `y`".  So `x^n` (i.e. "raising the string `x` to the `n`th power") naturally means "`n` copies of the string `x`, joined together".

This is mostly just a notational device, though multiplication (of ordinary real numbers) and string concatenation do share some abstract mathematical properties.  E.g. they are both associative: `(xy)z = x(yz)`, whether we're talking about multiplying numbers or joining strings.  (OTOH, `xy = yx` for real numbers but not for strings, in general.  But then matrix multiplication is not commutative either.)

Comment: Ohh, awesome explanation!! So in my case that means that l=0 in case pattern is only made out of a single charachter in length m?